# how to extract a subset of a rar file in google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a very big Rar files in my google drive which contain several subfloders. Now, I'd like to extract only a few subfolders (not all folder into colab). Is there any way for this?
or instance, suppose the zip file name is "Big folder.rar" which contains "folder1", "folder2", "folder3", "folder4", and "folder5". I only want to import and extract "folder1",and "folder4" into my google colab

How is it possible? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below command and run the cell

```
!unrar x "Big folder.rar" "/content/sample_data" "folder1" "folder4"
```

here you are trying to extract folder1, folder4 from Big folder.rar and extracting data to /content/sample_data

[More about unrar](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/unrar-1.html)